# How dangerous is it if someone knows your wireless routers password

Tags: security, wireless-router

We have both OSX and Windows 10 computers at home, and when guest come currently we give them our wireless routers password.

I am going to know going forward only give them our guest account password.

But I am just curious, I'm sure our password can easily be stolen since it is on so many peoples devices etc.

What can someone do with your wireless password?

Is the default settings on OSX and windows to prevent any remote access?

Comment: Just change the password.

Answer (score 0):

Most off the shelf routers with built-in guest networks are designed to let you give someone basic internet access without having to give them open access to your entire network.  So they can get to Google and stuff without being able to browse your networks shared files or devices.

In MOST cases, you should be safe, but I have read that there are some security concerns over poorly designed guest networks on some routers.  I'm not sure which routers are affected and the extent of those concerns though.

The basic thing to be concerned with is just making sure the people who connect to your guest network are trust worthy.  Even if they don't have direct access to shared network resources, they might still do things on your wifi that you won't want them to.

Or if it feels necessary, you can turn off your guest network when those users leave.  This will make sure that they only have access to the guest network while you're present.

Comment: And I'm sorry I just realized I missed part of the question.  "What can someone do with your wireless password".  

Literally anything you can do, they'll be able to do.  If you have openly shared files or devices, they'll be able to access them.

It doesn't give them direct access to your computers but it puts them on the inside of your secured network and makes it much easier to be able to scan your network for vulnerabilities if they were inclined.

Answer (score 0):

**Step one**, "going forward" is to **change your wireless password.** In a non-dense environment (if you are not physically near the house, you would not get signal, and you'd be at the house or noticeably out of place if you were sitting there connecting to the WiFi) I run an open guest network (no password) with client isolation (so guests cannot access/attack other guests) - in a more dense/apartment-type situation I use a guest password.

Your wireless password "type" should be WPA or WPA2 at minimum - "WEP" is outdated and very easily crackable.

Default settings on various OSes vary over time and are often not as restrictive as is generally considered good practice.

Anything that is open or shared on your network would be visible to someone with your password, and that also exposes you to a variety of port-scanning attacks, etc.